# Pass ID dynamically in div tag

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

Hi I have id:"network" in div class "parent", Here I have forloop which generate many IP's.
When I click particular parent IP it should call its child div.
How do I generate ids dynamically, so that I can place the child div in the for loop.
Or is there some other way to do this?

```
<div class="parent">
//$i= 1;
foreach($octetets as $octet){

echo "<a href='javascript:void(0);' id='network' value='$octet'>+".$octet.".0.0.0</a> <br />";
//$i++;
 }


<div class="child">
<?php
echo "<a href='javascript:void(0);'  id='network_test' ></a>";  
?>
</div>
</div>
```

I am using jquery to click the parent IP

```
$(".msg_head").click(function(){
$(this).next(".parent").slideToggle(600);
});

$(".child #network_test").click(function(){
$(this).next(".child").slideToggle(600);

});
```

Comment: there is a variable $i why you are not using it in the name of div?

Comment: Just a note... you should not set the `id` of each link in your `for` loop to the same value as ID's are meant to be unique across the entire document.

Comment: Ya I tried this like incrementing $i and appending it. id='network'.'$i'. But I could not proceed.

Answer (score 1):

So do:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.parent #network').click(function() {
        // Here you manipulate the child div
    });
});
```

Example: Add more links;

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.parent #network').click(function() {
        $('.child').append('<a href="#" id="network_test">Child ' + $(this).text() + '</a><br />');
    });
});
```